# Inline css work but external and internal css doesn't work in index.php

Tags: php, html, css

As the question suggests I have an index.php file with html in it and when I try to style it using external or internal css, it doesn't work. But inline css works. By the way I am using xampp on win7 to test the website. And the file structure looks like this c:/xampp/htdocs/test/index.php

Relevant html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->
        <!--This css file contains the css shown below as internal css-->       

        <style>
            body{
                background-color: blue;
                color: white;
            }
            .header{
                color: white;
            }
        </style>

        <?php
            function somefuntion(){
                /*I will be adding this function later once the html skeleton               
                is done.
                This function will be calculating some numbers based on the 
                current date and echoing it.*/
            }
        ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="header">
            <p>Spring</p>
        </section>
        <section class="body">
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can someone also explain why internal css is not working?

Solution found by  hRdCoder: missing " mark in the content attribute of meta tag.

Comment: Make sure you don't comment out your external CSS file in the header, or else it won't be applied.

Comment: I am having issues with both internal and external css so I comment out the external css file in the header when checking if internal css works and vice versa.

Comment: Try something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" <?php echo 'href="'.base_url().'/css/style.css"'; ?>>`

Comment: it says Fatal error: Call to undefined function base_url()

Comment: Sorry about that; typo. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" <?php echo 'href="/test/style.css"'; ?>>` this is if it's inside a folder called `test`. If not and file is in root, try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" <?php echo 'href="/style.css"'; ?>>`

Comment: or `<link href="/test/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` it's hard to say if your server's wanting to go through your root first. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` also. It might reveal errors.

Comment: Is it potentially possible that you are not actually viewing the right file in the local host? I.E. I have one folder, I can view the file via a web-browser normally or I can use my IDE to view it in the browser, both causing separate things to be viewed at times.

Comment: Also, to ensure that you're not misusing any CSS... You are expecting the outcome of your HTML file to be a complete blue background with white colored text? Correct? It should turn out like this: http://jsfiddle.net/x8e3f/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I have a table which I wasn't able to style due to the issue so I was adding random but highly visible style so I can check if css is working. Just my way of finding css related bugs.

Comment: Here is a link that will serve you well http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
```

Only things to check for are that you add the closing tag and that the style.css file is in the same directory as your index.php.

Edit:

I just noticed that in your  that you're missing the last set of quotation marks (") in the content attribute. Could that be affecting the rest of the page?

Comment: Yes, you need the href attribute path to actually find the css file in order to load any css from it.

Comment: No, I mean the `</link>`

Comment: Then likely the path might be incorrect, or there's a typo. Those are only ever the reason why I can't load external css at times. @Fred -ii- TIL the closing tag for "link" is optional.

Comment: What do you mean "optional"? Have you any documentation to back up this theory?

Comment: Just checked for typos and the path is correct too.

Comment: @Fred -ii- With the exception of XHTML, I meant "optional" as in you are allowed to leave them out if you wish to do so for the tags that allow it.

Comment: @Icarus I just noticed that in your <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> that you're missing the last set of quotation marks (") in the content attribute. Could that be affecting the rest of the page?

Comment: @hRdCoder you are my hero! This error has been haunting me for the last 6-ish hours! Also I am sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: @hRdCoder Good catch on the missing quote. Btw, that is `not` my DV.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It happens to me so often that I think I've developed an eye for this kind of error. :)

Comment: @hRdCoder I suggest you place a copy of [`your comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582164/inline-css-work-but-external-and-internal-css-doesnt-work-in-index-php#comment38080969_24582197) in your answer, that way it will be clear for future visitors to this question.

Comment: Good catch @Fred -ii-. I editted this answer with my comment. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you don't include the `<style></style>` tags in your external css file

Comment: The css files doesn't have any style tags.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. open css file through xampp or wampp.. like
open browser -> search localhost/your folder and then open css or js file ,now copy that address and paste in href or src.  hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

the answer could be as simple as adding a class or id to the html tag like lets say there is a button tag like this..
 `<button>open</button>`
and the code you wrote on external css is not working but inline does cuz there might be a class or id or the selector itself imposing the code without you knowing it so that's why it might not be working .That's why try adding a class or id to it like this..

```
<button class="btn">open</button>
 
 <style>
.btn {
 background-color:red;
 }
</style>
```

it might just work..

Answer (score -1):

there is something wrong with your path when linking your external css

is your index.php is in the same folder as your style.css?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

try to put it in a separate folder named css
then link it as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

you can also use firebug plugins for firefox or firebug lite plugin for chrome to check the errors

Comment: Tried with index.php and css file in same folder and in separate folders. Neither works.

Comment: really? can you post your folder structure?

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/test inside the test folder resides index.php and other files

Comment: try using the firebug plugin, it would really help you alot if youre into web development not just path issue but many more awesome things.

Comment: THanks for the suggestion. Will definitely do as the issue was due to a missing " mark.

Comment: oh. my bad didnt see it hahaha

in here right? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">